# How to avoid "lvalue required as unary ‘&’ " error in one line?

Tags: c, pointers, casting, initialization, constants

I know how to simply avoid the `lvalue required as unary ‘&’` error (as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22788026/error-lvalue-required-as-unary-operand))

What I try to do, is to avoid this error in ONE line.
Why? I have a lot of const defined, and in several part of the badly written code I am working on, this consts are used for initialization. I don't want to define an intermediary variable each time I use it...

in the following example I need intermediate value 't'

```
int  * p;
const int q = 88;
int t = (int)q; //works but I have to add for each time I used q, an intermediate variable.
p = &t;
printf("p: %u\n",*p);
```

in the following example I don't need intermediate value 't' (but it does not work)

```
int  * p;
const int q = 88;
p = &((int)q); //what I would like to do but raises:  error: lvalue required as unary ‘&’ operand
printf("p: %u\n",*p);
```

Is there any one-line-way?
Using #defines could be a hint...

Note: I obsiously don't want any warning in my compilation, as I am correcting MISRA violation:
`Cast from 'const int *' removes 'const' qualifier (MISRAC2012-RULE_11_8.a)`

Note: p is not declared as const int, because p is modified later. p use i to init itself.

---

The solution given by 'StoryTeller - Unslander Monica' works if the variable is simple: `p = &((int){i});`

However this does not apply to structures:

```
    typedef struct
    {
        int i;
        int j;
    }struct_t;
    
    const struct_t q = {.i=12,.j=88};
    printf("q: %u - %u\n",q.i,q.j);
    
    struct_t  * p = &((struct_t){q});
    printf("p: %u - %u\n",p->i,p->j);
```

The compilation of which raises `error: incompatible types when initializing type ‘int’ using type ‘struct_t {aka const struct }’`

Comment: You have to cast the result of `&`... `(int *)(&i)`

Comment: no it will raise the MISRA error

Comment: What *purpose* is the code supposed to fulfil? I’m asking since obviously the first and second code aren’t at all equivalent, even in spirit. The first code creates a pointer to a variable `j`, and `i` is completely unused. The second code seems to attempt to create a pointer to the variable `i` (ignoring that it doesn’t work). So what do you need the pointer for? What should it point to?

Comment: sorry, my example was wrong, it was missing the use of i

Comment: @GuillaumeD OK but that edit doesn’t clarify my question. It’s still unclear what you need `p` for, what it should point to, and how it’s used.

Comment: There is one important detail missing in this question: **Why is `p` not declared `const int *`?** That would solve the problem in const-correct way.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow I do agree, but it's not mine and I have to get it finished for yesterday

Comment: @StoryTellerUnslanderMonica   could you explain why you did remove your answer? thanks

Comment: @user694733  p is not declared as const int, because it is modified later. p use i to init itself.

Comment: @GuillaumeD Are you modifying `p` later, or `*p`?  If it's the former, you can define it as `const int *`.

Comment: @GuillaumeD, one can form compound literals for structure types, too.  In fact, that's their main use case.  Do a little research on the term ("compound literal").  This all does have fairly strong code smell, but you haven't presented enough for us to suggest better alternatives.

Comment: @GuillaumeD - Because you shifted the goal posts. And I'm not inclined to scurry and try to address it immediately, nor am I partial to accumulating downvotes and comments about the inadequacy of my proposed solution in the meanwhile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A cast expression like `(int)i` is indeed not an lvalue. A [compound literal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/compound_literal), however, *is* an lvalue:

```
p = &(int){i};
```

It essentially produces an anonymous integer with automatic storage duration that is initialized from `i`, and persists until the end of the enclosing scope.

So you also get a valid pointer.

---

Using a structure changes the playing field a bit. Since the semantics of initializer lists vary between scalars and aggregates. But that doesn't mean we can't work in a uniform fashion. Simply create an array (of 1 element), so we *always* initialize an enclosing aggregate. Now both code snippets work

```
// p = (int[]){i};
struct_t *p = (struct_t[]){q};
```

Though the conversion to a pointer is implicit (which may spark debate).

Comment: OK but what would be the purpose of this code?

Comment: @KonradRudolph - To create a one-of object which is typically passed into a function by pointer.

Comment: exactly what I was looking for.. purpose? correcting misra violations!

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica Why not just use a regular automatic variable for that purpose?

Comment: @KonradRudolph - Because it needs to have a name. And not everything deserves a name. C++ solves this on the language level, we can bind a temporary to a const lvalue reference. But C has no references. And the address-of operator may only be applied to lvalues. So C99 introduced unnamed lvalues. That's pretty much all there is to it.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica OK, I confess that I still don’t understand. Your code *still* has a name, `p`. In fact, your code now potentially has *more* names than my code would (`p` and `i`, vs. only `i` in my code, or potentially an unrelated `j` if I need a non-const copy of `i`).

Comment: @KonradRudolph - I'd chalk it up to the OP reducing their problem a bit too much. But really, getting an address out of an unnamed object is the most common use of compound literals. There's a fair share of C API's that accept an address of a struct holding some sort of configuration. And it's typically a one-of thing.

Comment: The parenthetical clutter is unnecessary; `&(int){i}` suffices.

Comment: @EricPostpischil - True, but I typically enjoy having a minimal diff to what the OP posted if I can. It's a habit.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica I have edited my post because your answer works for simple variable but not structures